Legit profits or likely scam?
new to bitcoin world and I got hooked up with a trader calling himself David O. Nelson and the website was MajorfxHawk.
I have doubts to it’s authenticity especially when I incurred an upgrade fee when my $1,000 investment in 5 days earned $40,000 in profits.
Repeatedly promised I would have access to profits as soon as I paid upgrade of $4,000.
It wasn’t tue and that $5,000 investment had now earned $80,000.
They just sent my profits to Coinbase wallet and I have a Withdrawal Mempool tax of nearly $4,000 which needs to be paid before I have access.
I believe this is just another step in the scam. Paying this fee does not guarantee my money does it?
My brain says if I pay, the profit will magically disappear.
I would like to hear from more experienced traders.
Thank you.

Yep. Scam. There was never any profit. You lost it all the second you sent it.

See first point at How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?
